# Get number of google search result with googlesearch module

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a piece of the code I'm working on:

```
search(test, tld = 'com', num = 1, start = 0, stop = 2, pause = 2.0)
```

I want the program to tell me if it found more than 1 results in google and also you should `from googlesearch import search`. (for importing the module.)

I tried to use enumerate but I still didn't find out.
And I also searched StackOverflow but still didn't give me what I want(to get the number of google search result **with googlesearch module**)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [this library](https://github.com/anthonyhseb/googlesearch), response.results is an iterable. Hence, you can convert it to a list using the list function, at which point it will have a length attribute, accessible using the len builtin.